# Is there a way to have only controllers in Totem?

Tags: totem

What I want is to have only controllers without video window. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you using it for audio files?

Comment: Yes, for audio files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Totem. Use Banshee or RhythmBox, or another specialist audio player.

Banshee can be closed down completely, once the audio is playing, and controlled from the volume indicator at the top right of Unity.

I know some audio files open with Totem by default, but you can open them with Banshee by right-clicking on them, and using the menu.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible now. You can disable visualization(Preference>Display) but it will shows a static totem icon, but video window will not disappear.

with Visualization:

[image]

without Visualization:

[image]

Comment: This is not what I want which is simply just a controllers bar. Thank you for response. I will probably have to look for another software. Any recommendations?

Comment: smplayer, rhythmbox